# ¿Cómo vincular un archivo JS correctamente? Aparece el error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html

En esta imagen se puede observar que en la línea 6 es donde la consola nos indica que tengo un problema, pero por qué, no sé. Según mi entendimiento está bien el vínculo.

```
<head>
    <title>Wordle Juego</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>        
</head>
```

[image: Consola]

Comment: Tenes el .html y el .js en el mismo directorio? estas usando alguna extension como Live Server para correrla?

Comment: Siempre describe qué aparece en la imagen. El código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_: no todos pueden ver las imágenes.